# HsqlException: General Error when calling a stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, hsqldb

I'm trying to write an integration test for a DAO that calls a stored procedure.  I've created an embedded HSQL database from a test file that simply creates a table, populates it, and a simple stored procedure that returns the results of the table:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetAvailableServices()
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT FeatureType FROM PUBLIC.service_areas ;
    OPEN result;
END/;
```

The code to create the database is as follows. The database is created and populated properly.

```java
        db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("db/sql/getAvailableServicesStoredProcedure.sql")
                .setSeparator("/;")
                .build();
```

My test fails when trying to call the stored procedure with `General error; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: General error` which is ultimately caused by

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: General error
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

I got the HSQLDB console running and confirmed that my stored procedure was indeed created (it is listed under `information_schema.routines`), however when I try calling the stored procedure directly in the console with `call usp_GetAvailableServices()`, I am still presented with `General error / Error Code: -458 / State: S1000`

This leads me to believe that I have an error in my create procedure syntax, (seems correct per http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_cursors) or that I don't know how to properly call a routine in HSQLDB.

The code that calls the live stored procedure using SqlServer works properly.  It's only HSQLDB that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is fine. Because it uses `OPEN cursorname CURSOR`, you cannot call it with DatabaseManager or SqlTool. You need to call it this way with JDBC using execute():

```
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(
        "call usp_GetAvailableServices()");
    boolean isResult = cs.execute();

    assertFalse(isResult);

    isResult = cs.getMoreResults();

    ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();

    rs.next();
    // do something with the rs row
    rs.close();
```

Note the need for the getMoreResults() call.

Alternatively, use executeQuery() to avoid the extra call.

```
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(
        "call usp_GetAvailableServices()");

    ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();

    rs.next();
    // do something with the rs row
    rs.close();
```

The next version, currently available as snapshot jar from http://hsqldb.org/downlaod, supports cs.execute() and cs.getResultSet() without cs.getMoreResults().

```
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(
        "call usp_GetAvailableServices()");
    boolean isResult = cs.execute();

    ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();

    rs.next();
    // do something with the rs row
    rs.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me understand the problem.  The solution as prescribed won't work for me because it requires me to change the code I am testing.

Is it possible to return the result set of the query in the stored procedure without a cursor?  My dataset will always be very small.

Comment: Please add the Java code that works with SqlServer to your question.

Comment: I was able to answer my question using the information provided here.  The issue was indeed the cursor.  HSQLDB is not able to return a ResultSet without a cursor, however a Function can return a table that can mimic the behavior of the actual stored procedure without using a cursor.